# JMS listener in Spring initiates two Consumer

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, consumer

I am new Spring(3.1.2) and JMS. I am trying to consume a JMS message (QUEUE) which is being sent by an ActiveMQ server. I have done the below configuration in Spring xml file.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://xx.xx.xxx.144:61616" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="videovantage-nslij" />                   <!-- testQ -->
</bean>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="1" >
    <jms:listener destination="videovantage-nslij" ref="messageReceiver"
        method="processMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Now I am able to receive JMS messages. But the problem is When i start the JBOSS server(7.1.1) I see two consumers from the same machine. When i do netstat i get the below, notice that activemq port 61616 is listening twice.

```
TCP    xx.xxx.xxx.150:51234   xx.xxx.xxx.144:61616    ESTABLISHED     1044
TCP    xx.xxx.xxx.150:51235   xx.xxx.xxx.190:27017   ESTABLISHED     1044
TCP    xx.xxx.xxx.150:51236   xx.xxx.xxx.144:61616    ESTABLISHED     1044
```

Not sure why two consumers are getting created. Any suggestion or guidance will be very helpful. Please let me know if any additional details are required.

Thanks in advance,
Gopi